# MongoDB suddenly refusing java driver connections

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I've been working on a server project that uses a mongoDB backend (which is hosted on the same machine), then suddenly one day mongoDB stopped accepting connections from the java driver. When I SSH into the machine and execute the command `mongo` it allows me to connect and query. Since it was working before with the same version of the software running that is running now.

Useful Information:
MongoDB Version: `3.2.6`
Mongo Java Driver Version: `3.2.2`
Code used to connect: `database = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017).getDatabase("network");`
Error Message: http://pastebin.com/KYandG2w

Any additional information required please just ask.

Comment: is it on linux? Can u check the ulimit by $ ulimit -a?

Comment: Actually the system admin messed up the hosts file in etc so that localhost stopped working.